# Reduce font size in message list in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am using Outlook 2016 (installed on my PC, not via the web), and I have the following issue:

[image: Screenshot showing font issue]

The font called out by number 1 appears to be 11px tall, while the subject lines (called out by number 2) appear to be 9px tall. Is there a way I can force them to be the same size? I'm specifically interested in reducing the height of number 1 (I've seen that I can increase the height of #2, but I want to view more messages, not fewer).

I noted that adjusting the fonts in the *Conditional Formatting* section of the *View Settings* panel seems to make things smaller, but only when those conditions are met (e.g. a message is unread). Are there other places where this font might be specified? I'm using the Compact View in my mail list, with 0 lines of message preview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the Conditional Formatting section and change the conditions there, for unread messages to use "smaller" then add a new rule:

Name: read or whatever?
Font > smaller
Conditions > More choices : 
tick the option Only items that are: Choose Read.

Then click ok.

This should give you two rules, one for read messages and one for unread, both being smaller text sizes, ensure that unread are setup to have BOLD or something just to see unread messages?

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps with your resizing needs.